# Create a Hierarchical List with Pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make a list that looks like this:

[image]

I'm not sure if there is a name for this type of design, but "hierarchical list" has returned results on google that look like what I want so I am calling it that here. It is essentially the same UI pattern one sees with a filesystem browser for example (but that is not my use case).

I believe I could achieve this with an SVG, but I'm wondering if there is a way with pure CSS?

One thing I have tried is using nested `<ul>`s with a `before` pseudo element containing a unicode box drawing character like `┖`. What I have so far is this:

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

li.child::before {
  content: "┖";
  transform: scale(1, 1.8);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Root</li>
  <ul>
    <li class="child">Child Lv. 1</li>
    <ul>
      <li class="child">Child Lv. 2</li>
    </ul>
    <li class="child">Child Lv. 1</li>
    <ul>
      <li class="child">Child Lv. 2</li>
      <li class="child">Child Lv. 2</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

It looks pretty crummy, and I cant think of any way to actually have vertical lines that connect across the items as I do in my image example. Would appreciate any tricks that can help me come closest to my image example.

SVG might be acceptable but I don't want to add any heavyweight libraries just for this one UI component, so that's why I am asking for pure CSS.

Comment: I’d probably try to give the pseudo elements a border-left and -bottom (instead of the `┖` character) to achieve the lines. With the right width/height and position that should work quite well, I think.

Comment: I agree I could position them better, but my main concern is I don't think I'll ever be able to have the vertical line that connects the two `Child Lv. 1` boxes in my example image, unless I'm misunderstanding you

Comment: That line would be the border-left of the pseudo element inside the second Lv1 child. How high that element needs to be made, depends on how many children the first Lv1 has below it – so you’d need to count those upfront somehow. (Of course the whole thing will fall apart, if one of your items breaks into more than one line. Then it might need JS to calculate the needed height values dynamically.)

Comment: Ahh now I see what you mean by using a border, that sounds like it might work! Let me give it a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per @CBroe's advice on using borders in the pseudo-element this is what I came up with:

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

li.child::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1em;
  top: -0.5em;
  border-left-color: black;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  content: "";
  width: 1em;
  height: 1.1em;
}

li.child2::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1em;
  top: -2em;
  border-left-color: black;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  content: "";
  width: 1em;
  height: 2.5em;
}

li.child3::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1em;
  top: -3em;
  border-left-color: black;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  content: "";
  width: 1em;
  height: 3.5em;
}

body {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Root</li>
  <ul>
    <li class="child">Child Lv. 1</li>
    <ul>
      <li class="child">Child Lv. 2</li>
    </ul>
    <li class="child2">Child Lv. 1</li>
    <ul>
      <li class="child">Child Lv. 2</li>
      <li class="child">Child Lv. 2</li>
    </ul>
    <li class="child3">Child Lv. 1</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

It looks nearly perfect! We just need to calculate how many `<li>` elements above the current `<li>` are not at the same indentation level to determine the class of the element, which should be easy to do with a little javascript.

Thanks @CBroe!